# Overflow content causes border removal (CSS and AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm seeing some rather strange behavior with overflow content in my application. If you take a look at the [codepen](http://codepen.io/danielyaa5/pen/xVpbpL) and scroll horizontally you'll see that once you start scrolling the border on the `.track` divs or possibly the `.cell` divs is removed. Any help much appreciated.

#### HTML

```
<section ng-app="netJamApp">
  <section ng-controller="ProjectController" id="project">
    <div class="tracks">
      <div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(pref.NUM_TRACKS) track by $index" class="track">
        <div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(cellsPerTrack(240)) track by $index" class="cell"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```css
#project {
  padding: 20px;
}
#project .tracks {
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#project .tracks .track {
  font-size: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}
#project .tracks .track:first-child {
  border: 1px solid #343436;
}
#project .tracks .track:not(first-child) {
  border: 1px solid #343436;
  border-top: none;
}
#project .tracks .cell {
  min-width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #272822;
  border-right: 2px solid #343436;
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.slide-in-left {
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
  animation-duration: 250ms;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

#### Angular

```
var app = angular.module('netJamApp', []);

/* PROJECT CONTROLER */
app.controller('ProjectController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  // INIT SCOPE VARS
  $scope.pref = {};
  $scope.pref.NUM_TRACKS = 5;
  $scope.pref.MIN_CELLS_PER_TRACK = 20;
  $scope.pref.CELL_LENGTH = 15;
  $scope.pref.PADDING_CELLS = 10;

  // HELPERS 

  //used for ng-repeat to repeat a given number of times
  $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);
  };

  // determine the number of cells to insert inside of a track
  $scope.cellsPerTrack = function(audioclip_len) {
    var cells = audioclip_len / $scope.pref.CELL_LENGTH + $scope.pref.PADDING_CELLS;
    return Math.ceil(Math.max(cells, $scope.pref.MIN_CELLS_PER_TRACK));
  };
}]);
/* project controller */
```

Comment: I have encountered this issue. It is because of the initial width being limited. I know a hack, just trying it out on your codepen.

Comment: Yikes... Tried my level best man. Sorry, I give up.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an `outline` CSS rule instead of `border`.

Editing your CSS like this would fix the issue:

```
.cell {
  min-width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background: $sublime-black;
  //border-right: 2px solid $codepen-grey;  <-- replace with outline
  outline:2px solid $codepen-grey;
}
```

**[Working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyryNX)**

Comment: That's wow, but looks like a hack. If you inspect and find the width of the row div with `class="track ng-scope"`, it still doesn't use the full width. Can you find why? This just works as a presentational way. `:)`